# A strange phenomena using JQ selector with some variable identifiers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add come mouseover and mouseout functions to a series classes. So I use JQ selectors with variables in a loop:

```
for(i=1;i<=2;i++){
    cid='.Cid'+i;
    ccid='.CCid'+i;
    csid='.CSid'+i;     
    $(cid).mouseover(function(){
    $(ccid).addClass("RelatedMainComment");
    $(csid).addClass("RelatedMainComment");
    });
    $(cid).mouseout(function(){
        $(ccid).removeClass("RelatedMainComment");
        $(csid).removeClass("RelatedMainComment");
    });
    }
```

But it doesn't run correctly, It seems to add the last one class, which in the example it is the class "Cid2", the mouseover ande mouseout function. So I take an another experiment:

```
i=1;
    cid='.Cid'+i;
    ccid='.CCid'+i;
    csid='.CSid'+i;     
    $(cid).mouseover(function(){
    $(ccid).addClass("RelatedMainComment");
    $(csid).addClass("RelatedMainComment");
    });
    $(cid).mouseout(function(){
        $(ccid).removeClass("RelatedMainComment");
        $(csid).removeClass("RelatedMainComment");
    });
    i=2;
```

it's result is same with the former one .
besides,If the code is :

```
        for(i=2;i>=1;i--){
    cid='.Cid'+i;
    ccid='.CCid'+i;
    csid='.CSid'+i;     
    $(".Cid"+i).mouseover(function(){
    $(".CCid"+i).addClass("RelatedMainComment");
    $(".CSid"+i).addClass("RelatedMainComment");
    });
    $(".Cid"+i).mouseout(function(){
        $(".CCid"+i).removeClass("RelatedMainComment");
        $(".CSid"+i).removeClass("RelatedMainComment");
    });
    }
```

it can't work.
Can you explain why?

Comment: Class lack of closures, duplicate of about 1 million other questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

Javscript closures! Use an anonymous function with `i` as the param:

```
for(i=1;i<=2;i++){
    (function(i) {
        cid='.Cid'+i;
        ccid='.CCid'+i;
        csid='.CSid'+i;     
        $(cid).mouseover(function(){
            $(ccid).addClass("RelatedMainComment");
            $(csid).addClass("RelatedMainComment");
        });
        $(cid).mouseout(function(){
            $(ccid).removeClass("RelatedMainComment");
            $(csid).removeClass("RelatedMainComment");
        });
    })(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `ccid` is only used in the statement `$(ccid).addClass("RelatedMainComment");`  when you mouseover `$(cid)`.

By that time the value of `ccid` is no longer `'.CCid'+i` but has already become `'.CCid2'` and therefore it doesn't work as you have expected.

For the variable `ccid` in your function to stay as `'.CCid'+i`, one solution is to use [event.data](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/).